# Intent permissions and JobIntentService

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

I've got an app A that sends an intent to app B. App A has a file provider and share a file to B. It add the grants to the intent and it starts a service on B. B has an IntentService and process the intent. Now I want to change B to use a JobIntentService  according to the new Android O policy. However I can't call startService from A, so I modified my code to send an explicit broadcast instead. I added the uri in the clipdata. However when I receive the intent on app B, I've got a security exception.

App A:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myotherapp.fileprovider",
                            newFile);
Intent i = new Intent(INTENT_UPDATE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(at.name(), contentUri);
i.setClipData(clipData);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setPackage("com.myapp");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

App B:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    if (MyService.INTENT_UPDATE.equals(arg1.getAction())) {
        MyService.enqueueWork(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```

Stack:

```
Process: com.myapp, PID: 7690
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.myapp.MyReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10083 does not have permission to content://com.myotherapp.fileprovider/files/Q3hnMrF8BsOJeznpVLizkTB4H6LkI90T.csv [user 0]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3259)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10083 does not have permission to content://com.myotherapp.fileprovider/files/Q3hnMrF8BsOJeznpVLizkTB4H6LkI90T.csv [user 0]
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1948)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1894)
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:211)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.enqueue(JobSchedulerImpl.java:53)
    at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:314)
    at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:472)
    at com.myapp.MyService.enqueueWork(MyService.java:41)
    at com.myapp.myrec.onReceive(UpdateReceiver.java:21)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3252)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Edit:** I tried using a JobService using setClipData on a JobInfo. It doesn't work at all anyway.

Comment: In the code you use authority of the file provider "com.myapp.fileprovider", but the error is for "com.myotherapp.fileprovider". Is that intentional?

Comment: I just removed my real package, so yes.

Comment: Does it happen on both Android O and older versions?

Comment: I didn't try but the crash it's enough to say: don't use job scheduler when you have an intent with permissions.

Comment: "don't use job scheduler when you have an intent with permissions" -- that does not necessarily follow from your published analysis here. In `onReceive()`, try using the `Uri`. If that succeeds, *then* somehow `JobIntentService` is mangling things, as you purport. If, however, `onReceive()` itself fails to have permissions, then the problem is in how you are sending the broadcast. I have never tried granting permissions on a `Uri` in a broadcast, so I don't know if there are any particular tricks that you need for that.

Comment: If the app has the granted permission while the receiving component is alive, just for an experiment, you can try to make BR live enough time, for example with goAsync and see if the JobScheduler will be able to get the permission or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare The code worked on previous versions, but as explained by Ian Lake on g+, you can't use directly startService when there is a job in the middle, so you need to use a receiver, but as you can see it doesn't work at all, so *Houston we have a problem*.

Comment: @TpoM6oH As you can see from the stack, the receiver was still alive.

Comment: I would suggest to do that experiment just to make sure that we understand the stack correctly.

Comment: "The code worked on previous versions" -- according to your question, you did not have the broadcast in previous versions. "so you need to use a receiver, but as you can see it doesn't work at all" -- possibly. The key is narrowing down *exactly* where the permission problem creeps in. You are blaming `JobIntentService`, but it is somewhat more likely that the issue is in your broadcast, and I can think of at least one fix to try for that. This is why I suggested that you run a test to see if you can access the `Uri` in `onReceive()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to try but even if the problem is the receive (and I don't know what I can change to be honest) the problem is still there because you can't call startService.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found a solution but it's quite bad and in addition is not compliant with the FileProvider docs, so at this point I don't know why it works, the permissions should stop when I call finish() but the job instead of failing now it works :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. The broadcast receiver doesn't receive the permissions and you can't call `startService` so you have only a tricky way to use a Job service in this case. I created a no display activity to forward the intent:

```
public class ProxyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyService.enqueueWork(this, getIntent());
        finish();
    }
}
```

However I'm not totally sure of this solution because the activity can dispatch only one intent per-time. If you have multiples intents is a problem. You could use a launchMode with single instance and use onHandleIntent(), a good idea but you can't use the theme no display anymore and you don't know exactly when you can call finish().

**Edit:** As explained by Ian Lake (Google) "...as you've found, URI permissions can indeed be chained to other components by passing through the ClipData." and clip data are automatically created by the system when you use setData() or setDataAndType() on Api 16+, so this explains why it works, however the problem of a single intent is still there.

**Edit2:** I found a better solution at least in my case, use a brodcast receiver but the caller uses `context.grantUriPermissions()` method.

Comment: Try terminating your service's process after calling `enqueueWork()` but before your work actually attempts to use the `Uri`. It might be tricky to do that, and it would not happen a lot in production. But, my guess is that you will not have access to the content identified by the `Uri` in that situation, because the permission grant will lapse when your process terminates.

Comment: I could try but in theory the job in android O should works, it's the reason why they added setclipdata to the jobinfo, exactly to work with permissions. Do you know why this code works? According to the file provider docs, the permission should ends when I call finish() but the job still works.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs of `FileProvider` they say that

> A content URI allows you to grant read and write access using temporary access permissions. When you create an Intent containing a content URI, in order to send the content URI to a client app, you can also call Intent.setFlags() to add permissions. These permissions are available to the client app for as long as the stack for a receiving Activity is active. For an Intent going to a Service, the permissions are available as long as the Service is running.

My guess is that the permission is gone when you exit the broadcast receiver's `onReceive` method.

**Solution:**
So turned out that the problem is that Broadcast Receiver is not supported, and you can target only activities and services, as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: As you can see from the stack, I still was in onReceive

Comment: I see, so do you try to read the file in the broadcast receiver?

Comment: No and I can't, the file is really big and the app could end with ANR.

Comment: If you remove the call to the service does the app still crash? I'm just trying to locate the problem. Since it crashes on the BR stage maybe the problem has nothing to do with the JobIntentService?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash. The problem is quite clear, the grants are not transferred to the system job service when you try to call enqueue. At this point it's a big bug IMHO.